# SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.sigalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have referenced below two libraries dynamically in my page. When I browse my application below mentioned error did not come in Chrome browser. But in Internet Explorer the error occurs.

```
var signalRLibrary = document.createElement('script');
signalRLibrary.type = "text/javascript";
signalRLibrary.src = 'jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(signalRLibrary);

var signlaRHub = document.createElement('script');
signlaRHub.type = "text/javascript";
signlaRHub.src = "~/signalr/hubs";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(signlaRHub);
```

During page load I got below error as SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.

```
if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have a `~/signalr/js` field in your `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` this error is possible. Please check it and make changes accordingly.

Comment: @EmreBolat, My project is not developed by using MVC. I have referenced above mentioned libraries in HTML page. Above code is working fine in Chrome browser. Not working in IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A JavaScript client requires references to jQuery and the SignalR core
>   JavaScript file. The jQuery version must be 1.6.4 or major later
>   versions, such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1. If you decide to use the
>   generated proxy, you also need a reference to the SignalR generated
>   proxy JavaScript file. The following example shows what the references
>   might look like in an HTML page that uses the generated proxy.
>
> ```
> <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
> <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
> <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
> ```
>
> **These references must be included in this order: jQuery first, SignalR
>   core after that, and SignalR proxies last.**
>   - from [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#clientsetup)

Your problem is that, somehow, the order in what you are loading the references is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`100% working if you want to debug on locally.`
how to debug SingalR locally?

Answer : on cshtml page drag and drop js jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js in this way.Don't use min.js for debug and use this version for locally debug mode.

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js"></script>`
`<script src="@Url.Content("http://localhost:57305/signalr/hubs")"></script>`

Download all supported Signal R js from cdn.
https://www.cdnpkg.com/signalr.js/file/jquery.signalR.min.js/