# SignalR is not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, signalr

When I use `SignalR` in `HTML` page with `Javascript`, and call `SignalR` I am getting this error :

> SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced
>   before ~/signalr/js.

When I referred below stack overflow 
"[SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.sigalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522489/signalr-is-not-loaded-please-ensure-jquery-sigalr-x-js-is-referenced-before-s)"

It mentions like "references must be included in this order: jQuery first, SignalR core after that, and SignalR proxies last."

But in my case it is loading in order only. (See attached image) 
Kindly suggest me where I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: That is network tab, it doesn't have to be in the order in which data is loaded. Do you have `<script>` tags in the HTML. Check their order.

Comment: What do the script tags in your HTML look like?

Comment: Are you loading `async` by any chance?

Comment: I had followed order is 1) jquery-1.6.4.min.js  2)jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js 3) hubs.js

Answer (score 2):

Following is the structure of References to be followed while using `SignalR` in HTML Page.

```
versions can vary according to your project.
```

[image: Signal Ref.]

Comment: DownVoters, remember to explain the reason for downvoting